# Existing work on $\Delta u=c-h e^{u}$ on compact manifold with dimension n, I have read J.Kazdan's work, the condition $c > 0, n \ge 3$ is not solved

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I'm reading [Prof. Kazdan's lectures](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ekazdan/japan/japan.pdf)

At page 69, Prof. Kazdan describes the research on the $\Delta u=c-h e^{u}$ PDE on a compact $n$-dimensional manifold before 1983. (Here $c$ is a constant while $h$ is a smooth function).

In this lectures, the condition $c > 0$ is not fully solved, and we only have some results for $n = 2$: the reason we can't find here results for higher dimensions is that he uses the variational method and Moser-Trudinger inequality for dimension $2$.

I tried to find recent works dealing with the conditions $c > 0$  and $n \ge 3$, but I didn't get any good result. Does anyone know about this ?

Comment: Here’s a suggestion: look at the citations on Mathscinet

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!